# GCM "registration id" is not registered anymore

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the steps given in Google GcmClient app and generate registrationId which is stored in my SharedPrefs.
In this way, register-id is re-generated only if the appVersion is changed.

This reg-id is sent to my server (based on Rails) and notifications are sent to the android device through a GCM gem (https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm).

**The problem: Sometimes the server receives "not registered" response although the same register-id has worked just a minutes before the failure.**

When that happened, I tried to "clear data" and the newly generated reg-id is different from the last one...
**Is is possible that a registration-id is expired without the application is updated (of course I'm not calling unregister)?**

I read the posts on similar problems and google it but still can't determine what is common for all those failures.
The issue was occurred also when I download the app from GoogleStore (in production) and without updating the app.

The main method which registers to GCM:

```
public static void register(Context context, IGcmRegisterationListener listener) {
    try {
        MyLog.v("GcmClient: Registering for GCM...");
        Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
        //  GCM registration.
        if (checkPlayServices(appContext)) {
            MyLog.v("GcmClient: Looking for GCM regId locally");
            String currentRegId = getRegistrationIdFromPrefs(appContext);

            if (currentRegId == null) {
                MyLog.v("GcmClient: GCM regId not found.");
                registerInBackground(appContext, listener);
            }
            else {
                MyLog.v("GcmClient: GCM regId found: " + currentRegId);
                listener.onGcmRegistered(context, currentRegId);
            }
        } else {
            MyLog.i("GcmClient: No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
            listener.onGcmRegistrationFailed();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MyLog.i("GcmClient: GCM registration failed: " + Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        listener.onGcmRegistrationFailed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ? Even I am facing the same issue