# GCM 'Error : Not Registered' on cordova ionic application

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework

I am using ionic platform to develop my application, but I don't think that affects the way gcm works.

I am using a sender Id and registering my application to gcm to get a registration_id, everything seems to work fine upto a certain time. After which it seems that the registration_id expires by itself. I am having almost the same problem what this guy has : [GCM "registration id" is not registered anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472576/gcm-registration-id-is-not-registered-anymore)

Comment: Did you find a satisfying answer to your question? I get exctly the same issue. Arround 1% of the notificatins I sent give NotRegistered

Comment: @alexislg i found that almost all the tutorials i followed had a unregister call "i have no idea why" i just removed that unregister an the app started working smoothly

Comment: @alexislg also, know that calling register and then unregister one after the other will not unregister a device instantly it still has a ttl of 24 hours before it actually expires, in this period google keeps giving canonical ids, sorry to say  but the documentation by google looks like reading a legal notice

Answer (score 0):

So you can use exponential back off as described [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#automatic-retry-using-exponential-back-off) and use retry logic to fetch registerationID.

Another scenario is when the registrationID is indeed expired, use refresh token as advised in the official docs [here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation#generate_a_token).

Also pay attention to the note, GCM register() is deprecated. So I would suggest to use [Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) to handle registrationID.

Comment: Thanks. How can we use instance id API with Cordova??

Comment: You just need a plug in with push compatibility and other than that the registration implementation would be the same as it is in the documentation. Here's one example of such plugin: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Comment: This is the plugin I'm using but it is using GCM register, not Instance ID API, is it?

Comment: Seems like they have implemented intent service but not InstanceID. Which may or may not be the problem. Refer to this example for implementing InstanceID: https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/logic/InstanceIdHelper.java

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the cordova Push Plugin itself.

See this PR it might solve this issue

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/497